# Make a modified copy of the xmls and put them in the corresponding folders?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this folder, that has these in it:

[image: folder image]

And each xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<Metadata version="1.0">
    <CODE_OK>51041</CODE_OK>
    <DeliveryDate>13/08/2018</DeliveryDate>
```

The folders you saw in the picture are empty.

I want for each folder (see picture for help) to make a copy of each xml(there are 2 xmls) you saw that have the number:  `<CODE_OK>51041</CODE_OK>` in the xml replaced by the number in the name of their folder.

Here is the code that made the folders:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = path
df = pd.read_csv(path)
for i in df["col1"].astype(str):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, i))
```

How to proceed with the idea described?

Can you at least tell me where to begin. This is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this:

```
import os
from xml.dom import minidom
import shutil
folder_path = "D:/py_projects/test"
folder_name = "test"
root = os.listdir(folder_path)
xmls = []
folders = []
for file in root:
    if file.find(".xml") != -1:
        xmls.append(file)
    else:
        folders.append(file)
for xml in xmls:
    for folder in folders:
        shutil.copy(folder_path+"/"+xml, folder_path+"/"+folder+"/"+xml)
        dom = minidom.parse(folder_path + "/" + xml)
        root = dom.documentElement
        code_ok = root.getElementsByTagName("Code_OK")
        for i in range(len(code_ok)):
            print(code_ok[i].firstChild.data)
            code_ok[i].firstChild.data = folder
            print(code_ok[i].firstChild.data)
        fileHandle = open(folder_path+"/"+folder+"/"+xml, 'w')
        dom.writexml(fileHandle, ' ', ' ', ' ', 'UTF-8')
        fileHandle.close()
```

I use another xlm file since the file you offered is not correct.
Here is the example xlm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
    <maxid>4</maxid>
    <Code_OK>12324</Code_OK>
    <login username="pytest" passwd='123456'>
        <caption>Python</caption>
        <item id="4">
            <caption>test</caption>
        </item>
    </login>
    <item id="2">
        <caption>Zope</caption>
    </item>
</catalog>
```

has a initial value of '1234', and I have two folders("1" and "2" in "test").Like this:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1dbw.png)
This is the result:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbpAq.png)